# Adobe dreamweaver - how do I set default positioning of divs to percent instead of pixels

Tags: css, layout, dreamweaver

In dreamweaver while positioning the controls (design tab) the css position values (left, top etc) are generated in pixels. Is there any setting through which I can get the values generated in percentages(%) ?

Update: Added my current layout for reference.
Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Properties pane, you scroll down to the CSS properties you want, (eg: position) and use the select box to choose your type of positioning.

Use the same pane to scroll to top, left or whichever and there will be two select boxes side by side, the first one is for the value, the other for the measurement.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to scroll down in the properties pane. I have attached a screenshot of my layout with properties pane. Am I missing some thing ? (I'm using Dreamviewer CS5)

Comment: @ivymike: the properties pane on the right hand side is what I meant :) I'll attach a screenshot too.

Comment: Hi Kyle@ Thanks a lot for the help :). My requirement is a little different though. I can manually set the value, type(%) as you have suggested but after setting this and going back to the design to drag and drop/resize the divs (because its kind of difficult to to guess the % correct), dreamviewer updates the values back to pixels :(. Is it possible to force dreamviewer to update these values in % instead of pixels ?

Comment: @ivymike, The moment you drag and drop the divs, they are positioned exactly at the point you drop them, meaning at the exact pixel position, there is no way to let Dreamweaver know that you mean to use the drop position as a percentage of the current screen size. You must stop using drag and drop if you want to be using positioning by percentages, EMs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to figure the percentage if you know the height and width of the page.
You can use drag and drop to size your container and place your them where you want them to be. Divide Dreamweaver's top and height pixels for the container by the page height. And divide Dreamweaver's left and width pixels for the container by the width of the page. It's a bit of work but it can be done.